# jquery bootstrap-multiselect, search using non consecutive words

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-multiselect

Is it possible to modify https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect search functionality to search using non consecutive multiple words?

For example in the following, they want show all options that have "one" and "two" by searching using "one two"

1) One and Two
2) Two and One
3) Blue
4) Green and Blue

The result should show 1) and 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

recommended to use special characters like `;`
in the 1070 line:

```
var queryValues = this.query.split(";");
for(var i = 0;i<queryValues.length;i++){
queryValues[i].trim();
if (this.options.enableFullValueFiltering && this.options.filterBehavior !== 'both') {
        var valueToMatch = filterCandidate.trim().substring(0, queryValues[i].length);
        if (queryValues[i].indexOf(valueToMatch) > -1) {
            showElement = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    else if (filterCandidate.indexOf(queryValues[i]) > -1) {
        showElement = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

I fork a branch https://github.com/catzaizai/bootstrap-multiselect

Comment: I preferred your solution, with a slight modification to use space to split instead of ;

Answer (score 1):

`bootstrap-multiselect` has already feature `onFiltering`, you refer to this [line](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/blob/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js#L202) of source code in `bootstrap-multiselect` Github repository.

```
this.options.onFiltering = $.proxy(this.options.onFiltering, this);
```

But doesn't release yet, so i try to copy and paste in my fiddle and implement using `onFiltering`.

In `onFiltering`, Following this code.

```
var search_query = $("#example-filterBehavior").next(".btn-group").find('.multiselect-search').val().split(' ');
var search_label = $('#example-filterBehavior').next('.btn-group').find('.multiselect-container > li:not(".multiselect-item.filter")');
search_label.each(function(idx, elem) {
  $(elem).css('display', 'none');
  $(search_query).each(function(q_idx, q_elem) {
    if ($(elem).find('input').val().indexOf(q_elem) > -1) {
      $(elem).css('display', 'list-item');
      $(elem).removeClass('filter-hidden');
    } else {
      $(elem).css('display', 'none');
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SeokjunHong/7ekk7frL/)

Try to type `one two` or `Blue Green`.